# Swift-4: How to assign NSArray of NSDictionary values to another NSDictionary variable and how do i get value for key from NSDictionary

Tags: swift, tableview, swift4

In objective C we assign NSArray of dictionary values to NSDictionary variable and to get value for key as follows,`NSDictionary *dictValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`and `cell.name.text = [dictValue valueForKey:"customer_name"]` so how to do the above coding in swift-4. The way i declared NSArray variable,assined array of dictionary values to another NSDictionary and way of getting value from the NSDictionary.

```
var leadsArray = [NSArray]() /* Declared NSArray Variable */
let dictValue = larray[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary! /* Assigning each array of dictionary by row count */
cell.label1.text = dictValue["customer_name"] /* Getting valuefor key from NSDictionary Varibale */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var dictValue = array[indexPath.row] as? [AnyHashable: Any]
cell.name.text = dictValue?["customer_name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like:

```
let arrResponse = yourRespons as! [String:Any]

let name = arrResponse["customer_name"] as! String
print(name)
```